# Search text between two patterns that may or may not be on the same line in Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

My text file looks like the following:

```
line 1: pattern 1 <some text>
         2:  <some text>
         3:  <some text>
         4:  <some text>
         5: pattern 2
         6: pattern 1 <some text><some text> pattern 2 (same line)       
         7: <some other text>
```

I am looking for an optimized way to get the text entries between pattern 1 and pattern 2.

I would like to make a list of the text in between those patterns.

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output given that input.

Comment: Also, you should include a case like `pattern 1 <some text><some text> pattern 2 <some text> pattern 1 <some text><some text> pattern 2` all on one line in your example and make all the `<some text>` placeholders unique so when we test a potential solution we can tell where those blocks are coming from in the output to see if it's correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

With **awk**:

```
awk 'sub(/.*pattern 1/,""){on=1} sub(/pattern 2.*/,""){print; on=0} on;' yourfile
```

This works for both cases; for your file example, it produces:

```
 <some text>
2:  <some text>
3:  <some text>
4:  <some text>
5: 
 <some text><some text>
```

Comment: `/pattern 1/{gsub(/.*pattern 1/,""); on=1}` = `sub(/.*pattern 1/,""){on=1}`, `on{print}` = `on`, and if you rearrange your sections put the `on` in the middle then you don't need a separate `print` in the `on=0` block, i.e. `awk 'sub(/.*pattern 1/,""){on=1} on; sub(/pattern 2.*/,""){on=0}' yourfile`. It will fail when pattern2 for the previous block occurs on  the same line as pattern1 for the next block though.

Comment: OK I've shortened it like you suggested. I didn't remove print before "on=0" because this the trick to make it work for both cases. Thank you.

Comment: No, moving the `on;` to the middle as I showed is how to make it work in both cases. Leave it as `on{print}` if you prefer but do move it and get rid of the extra `print` in the terminating condition case so you're not doing the same thing (printing the current line) from multiple locations in your code.

Comment: If I move "on;" in the middle, it prints "pattern 2" before replacing it with empty string:
    `5: pattern 2`
    `<some text><some text> pattern 2`
Also, I'd like to wait for the asker to clarify the problem..

Comment: Ah, good point. The correct way to write it then would be `sub(/.*pattern 1/,""){on=1} on{if (sub(/pattern 2.*/,"")) on=0; print}'`. Yes, I'm also waiting for a response to my comment under the question before posting an answer - right now we don't know what the OPs real requirements are, we're all just guessing.